# H bridge's voltage, breaksdown when connected to a motor

Tags: transistors, motor, dc-motor, h-bridge, gain

My project is to build a car controlled by Bluetooth. first I'm building a H-bridge to control the motors. I'm using a 3v DC motor that needs a current of, 0.26A(no load) - 0.69A(with load) and I'm using 2N2222A transistor here is the data sheet (https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/P2N2222A-D.PDF) connected to a 9v battery datasheet

eventually the transistors base will be powered by a arduino or other micro controller but for now im just connecting the transistors to the battery.

The H-bridge is connected properly, when i test with an LED it works fine. however when i connect to my DC motor the voltage collapse. the transistors can handle the current. the battery can supply the current (worked when directly connected to power supply) required.

what i think could be the problem is not correctly understanding gain of my transistors. but i have tried different resistors in hopes of getting it right and tried to understand and use the formulas to calculate the correct base resistor values (which may have not been correct) but i am still having no luck with it.

if it helps i was following this Instructables tutorial: [H Bridge on a Breadboard](http://www.instructables.com/id/H-Bridge-on-a-Breadboard/)

[image]

I tried to make the schematic as neat as possible, i just wanted to show how every thing is wired exactly on my bread board.

Comment: UPDATE: i just randomly put a 100 ohm resistor on the base of the transistors and now the motor spins. (very slowly) however i still don't understand what happened.

Comment: You know, H-Bridge is called this way for a reason. Because it looks like H. What you draw is not just rough, it's rude. Why would any normal person even try to understand it?

Comment: Are both transistors NPN or is it just bad design? Please draw exactly what you have..

Comment: You know it's a H bridge so there is no excuse for such a bad diagram - draw it like a H bridge is my recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue #1 you have no freewheel diodes to facilitate the motor stator current to continue flowing when you stop enabling the BJT's

Issue #2 "rough design" needs to reflect EXACTLY what you have

Issue #3 you have NPN's for the top but no means to source their base (ie their base needs to be higher than 9V)

Issue #4 your NPN are the wrong way round if this is really what you have

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftaiqj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your circuit redrawn CLEARER

Comment: oh ya i was gonna place diodes after i got the H-bride working, by rough design i just ment it looked bad

Comment: nonono, they go down immediately.

Comment: preferably with mosfets and their drivers :)

Comment: 2 N channel and 2 P channel MOSFETs to add into Gregory's comment ^^"

Comment: Thats not a universal statement (I use 4 Ntypes but I work at 270Vdc) but in this case, at this voltage, for the simplicity YES ... but the OP has more problems then just that at the  moment

Comment: "*oh ya i was gonna place diodes after i got the H-bride working*". The bridge might last a few milliseconds without them. Can you add the diodes that quickly? The first transient will occur on the first switch of the motor. Why did you think these are optional?

Comment: Q1 and Q3 don't reflect what the op has drawn BTW. He has drawn them upside down and that would have been clear should he have taken the time to draw the circuit correctly in the first place! The transistor AMR is 600 mA and not suitable for his load also.

Comment: @Andyaka yup... the worst bit was I drew it like the OP but something in my brain just couldn't accept it. correcting

Comment: Hehe you dug yourself into a hole! +1 might alleviate the pain LOL.

Comment: @JonRB ok so i made my schematic a little better and added in the diodes. so the current flows the way i want it to. but when i attach it to my motor it still gives me the same proplem.

Comment: @ElQwerto thats not where the freewheel diodes go. Pulling the base of 2 of the BJT's will not produce teh expected results

Comment: @Transistor Ive place the diodes facing up and re did the schematic. is everything looking better now?

Comment: @ElQwerto: Improving. Now R1 and R4 resistors are permanently connected to V+. They shouldn't be. The battery polarity is backwards. The earth symbol on the battery is upside down. JonRB's shows the battery correctly (but his transistors are not drawn correctly).